# Batch script to duplicate a file multiple times using filenames from a list

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, file-copying

I'm Using a batchscript to duplicate a couple of PDFs and output them with different filenames each.

So far, What I have done is

```
SET Template=C:\Temp\template.pdf
copy /y %Template% .\%Class%\Apples_fruits.pdf 
copy /y %Template% .\%Class%\Oranges_fruits.pdf
copy /y %Template% .\%Class%\Grapes_fruits.pdf
copy /y %Template% .\%Class%\Bananas_fruits.pdf
copy /y %Template% .\%Class%\Strawberry_fruits.pdf
```

I want to do this without having to type the `copy /y` line each time. I'd like to have a list of 'fruits' in a `.txt` or `.xlsx` file and have batch use the items in the list as filenames.

For example:

```
Apples_fruits.pdf
Oranges_fruits.pdf
Grapes_fruits.pdf
Bananas_fruits.pdf
Strawberry_fruits.pdf
```

Comment: Other than not having the variable `class` defined, I don't see anything wrong with your code.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: You mention .txt and .xlsx extensions. I hope you are not changing the file extension when you are copying.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more clear.

I want to do this without having to type the copy /y line each time.

I'd like to have a list of 'fruits' in a .txt or .xlsx file and have batch use the items in the list as filenames.

Comment: you need a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop to iterate over a textfile.What you want to do is basically a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit.

The batch file and fruit.txt have to be in the same directory.

```
SET Template=%temp%\template.pdf
SET Class=Class
IF /i not exist %Class% md %Class%
FOR /f "delims=" %%g in ('type fruit.txt') do COPY /y %Template% .\%Class%\%%g_fruits.pdf
```

fruit.txt:

```
Apples
Oranges
Grapes
Bananas
Strawberry
```